# jsfでの話　xhtmlファイルではaudioタグは使えないのですか？

Tags: jsf, xhtml, audio

実行環境
統合開発環境 eclipse
payara server: version 5
jdk1.8

目標はaudioタグを記述し、
サーバーにデプロイした後、
google chromeにaudioとして表示させることです。

試したこととして
jsfではaudioタグが対応していなかったのでhtmlのaudioタグをfaceletsタグとして使えば表示されるのではないかと思い、記述して読み込ませた結果、読み込んでいるが表示されませんでした（図１）

また、ネットにaudioタグはjsfでは対応していないという記事があったのでそれを考慮して
primefacesというサードパーティのjarファイルをダウンロードして使ってみたものの
audioの部分は表示されませんでした(図２)

```
    図１
    <html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/javax.faces">
    <head>
    <title>testページへようこそ</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <audio jsf:id="audio"/>
    </body>
    </html>
    </pre>

    図２
    <html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:jsf="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/javax.faces">
    <head>
    <title>testページへようこそ</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <p:audio player="mp3" controls="true"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

図１、図２ともにタイトルは読み込んでいてaudioタグは表示されないといった様子でした。

検証ツールでみたのですが、audioタグは読み込まれていましたが表示されませんでした。
xhtmlでaudioタグをなんとか、使える方法をご存じの方などおられますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

手元で[こちら](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Video_and_audio_content#the_audio_element)を参考に`audio`タグを埋めてみましたが、特に問題なさそうに見えます。
(属性の真偽値を省略するとパースエラーになるので、`controls="controls"` のように書く必要はありました([参考](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6531738/4506703))。)

```html
<html
  lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
  <h:head>
    <title>Facelets Hello World</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <audio controls="controls">
      <source
        src="https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/viper.mp3"
        type="audio/mp3"
      />
      <source
        src="https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/viper.ogg"
        type="audio/ogg"
      />
      <p>
        Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio. Here is a
        <a href="https://mdn.github.io/learning-area/html/multimedia-and-embedding/video-and-audio-content/viper.mp3">link to the audio</a>
        instead.
      </p>
    </audio>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

---

([コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/88106/88109?noredirect=1#comment99924_88109)を受けて追記)

`<audio controls>` のように、属性値を省略する書き方は *attribute minimization* と呼ばれていました。
HTMLとは異なり、XHTML では仕様上 attribute minimization は許容されていません。
値を省略せず記述する必要があります。
この時の属性値は、属性名になります。
つまり、

```xml
<audio controls>
```

をminimizeせずに書くと

```xml
<audio controls="controls">
```

になります。

- 参考: [4.5. Attribute Minimization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/diffs.html#h-4.5) - XHTML™ 1.0 The Extensible HyperText Markup Language (Second Edition)

ちなみに、現在の HTML の仕様からは "attribute minimization" という用語は無くなっているようです。
また、今回のことに関する HTML の仕様は

- [2.3.2 Boolean attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes) - HTML Living Standard — Last Updated 30 March 2022

に書かれていますが、

> The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes.

とある通り、質問文にあるような `controls="true"` という書き方は HTML としても妥当ではありません。

> <audio controls="controls">でなぜ動くのかが知りたいです

prefix を付けていないので[デフォルト名前空間](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-defaultNS)である `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` で定義されたタグ(要するに、素のHTMLタグ)とみなされます。
なので Faceletプロセッサは特に何もせずそのまま出力するだけです。

Comment: まず、回答ありがとうございます。無事通りました。　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　『属性の真偽値を省略するとパースエラーになるので、controls="controls" のように書く必要はありました(参考)』の参考ページの意味が英文であることによって理解しずらいので説明をいただきたいです。そしてなぜcontrols="controls" のように書く必要はあるとわかったかが知りたいです

Comment: htmlのタグをxhtmlとして使うときhtmlのタグの属性値がない時controls="controls"のように書かないと処理されないということでよろしいですか？またここでききたいのですが<audio>が<audio jsf:controls=""controls>のようにxhtmlのタグにせず<audio controls="controls">でなぜ動くのかが知りたいです

Comment: 本当に適切な対応ありがとうございます。説明もわかりやすくそして仕様上、タグが最小にできないということも理解し、納得いたしました。ありがとうございました。